# Background tasks and activity

Tags: android

Has anyone any idea on how to solve the generic problems related to starting a task in background from an activity and when the task is finished posting the result to the activity that created ? (the activity might get destroyed in the meantime due to a orientation change ,or receiving a call , or might be in the process of destroying and recreation)

Answer (score 0):

Depending of what you are doing you might consider using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/app/Service.html) as well.